# phpエラー Uncaught ErrorException

Tags: php

Ubuntu 22.04 に HelpdeskZ というヘルプデスクツールをインストールしようとしています。
その際Webからインストール画面にアクセスするのですが、PHPのエラーでインストール画面を表示することができません。
どのように対処すればよいのでしょうか。

```
Deprecated: filter_var(): Passing null to parameter #3 ($options) of type array|int is deprecated in /var/www/html/helpdeskz-dev-2.0/hdz/framework/HTTP/Request.php on line 439

Fatal error: Uncaught ErrorException: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/html/helpdeskz-dev-2.0/hdz/app/Config/Events.php:33) in /var/www/html/helpdeskz-dev-2.0/hdz/framework/Debug/Exceptions.php:164 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: CodeIgniter\Debug\Exceptions->errorHandler() #1 /var/www/html/helpdeskz-dev-2.0/hdz/framework/Debug/Exceptions.php(164): header() #2 [internal function]: CodeIgniter\Debug\Exceptions->exceptionHandler() #3 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/helpdeskz-dev-2.0/hdz/framework/Debug/Exceptions.php on line 164

Fatal error: Uncaught ErrorException: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/html/helpdeskz-dev-2.0/hdz/app/Config/Events.php:33) in /var/www/html/helpdeskz-dev-2.0/hdz/framework/Debug/Exceptions.php:164 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: CodeIgniter\Debug\Exceptions->errorHandler() #1 /var/www/html/helpdeskz-dev-2.0/hdz/framework/Debug/Exceptions.php(164): header() #2 /var/www/html/helpdeskz-dev-2.0/hdz/framework/Debug/Exceptions.php(224): CodeIgniter\Debug\Exceptions->exceptionHandler() #3 [internal function]: CodeIgniter\Debug\Exceptions->shutdownHandler() #4 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/helpdeskz-dev-2.0/hdz/framework/Debug/Exceptions.php on line 164
```